# What was MVC invented for?

Tags: model-view-controller, web-deployment

I am new in web development, and read some wiki and discussions about MVC. However, the more I read, the more confusion I have about its design purpose.

I just want to know why is this design pattern invented? And what problem is it used to solve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sha404 is correct. If you continue reading and trying to understand it will come to you. You may just be over thinking it.

Comment: @sha404 Hi, maybe I am lack of the experience in real world development. Simple reading just made me confused.

Comment: please use the search function before asking questions that have been asked and answered on StackOverflow and elsewhere on the web before. Also, your question is very broad and unspecific while we expect programming questions about specific problems you encounter while coding. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/faq and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice for more details.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/modelViewController.html and http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#ModelViewController

Comment: @Gordon -- Yeah, Fowler's discussion is interesting ... and explains why the concept is largely inappropriate for modern GUI apps.

Comment: @HotLicks the pattern as such is not inappropriate. Just certain implementations are, which is why I always advocate to understand the pattern as being about the roles M, V and C and and not so much about how they talk to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of the MVC paradigm is in essence to ensure a form of separation of code. The problem that often arise when developing code is that the code is written in a succession, where each part follows another and where each part is directly dependent upon what the other parts are doing.

When working with a large project, maintaining and further developing the code can quickly become an issue. You could therefore argue, in a simplified manner, that what the MVC paradigm tries to do is to ensure that you separate business logic (e.g. the code that performs) from the presentation logic (the code that shows the results). But those two parts need to communicate with each other, which is what the controller is responsible for.

This allows for a clear structure of code where the different parts are more decoupled, meaning less dependent upon each other.

The separation also means that you work in a much more modular way, where each part interacts with the others through an interface (some defined functions and variables that are used to call upon other parts) so that you can change the underlying functionality without having the change other parts of your code, as long as your interface remains the same.

So the problem it tries to solve is to avoid having a code base that is so entangled that you can't change or add anything without breaking the code, meaning you have to modify the code in all sorts of places beyond where you made your original changes.

Comment: nitpick: the controller is presentation logic as well. Your explanation sounds like it was something inbetween the business logic and the presentation logic.

Answer (score 1):

To some degree it's a solution in search of a problem.

As a rather ancient programmer I'm well aware of the benefits of "separation of concerns", but (in my not-so-humble opinion) MVC doesn't do this very well, especially when implemented "cook-book" fashion.  Very often it just leads to a proliferation of modules, with three separate modules for every function, and no common code or common theme to tie things together and accomplish the *real* goal: minimize complexity and maximize reliability/maintainability.

"Classical" MVC is especially inappropriate in your typical phone GUI app, where, eg, management of a database table may be intimately connected to management of a corresponding table view.  Spreading the logic out among three different modules only makes things more complicated and harder to maintain.

What does often work well is to think about your data and understand what sorts of updates and queries will be required, then build a "wrapper" for the database (or whatever data storage you use), to "abstract" it and minimize the interactions between the DB and the rest of the system.  But planning this is *hard*, and a significant amount of trial and error is often required -- definitely not cook-book.

Similarly you can sometimes abstract other areas, but abstracting, say, a GUI interface is often too difficult to be worthwhile -- don't just write "wrappers" to say you did it.

Keep in mind that the authors of databases, GUI systems, app flow control mechanisms, etc, have already put considerable effort (sometimes too much) into abstracting those interfaces, so your further "abstraction" is often little more than an extra layer of calls (especially if you take the cook-book approach).

Answer (score 0):

Model view controller was created to separate concerns in code instead of crating a hodge podge all in a single blob. (Spaghetti code) the view code is merely presentation logic, the model is your objects representing your domain and the controller handle negotiating business logic and integrations to services on the backend.